# How do I use the MATLAB function randn in c++?

Tags: c++, matlab, random, interop, matlab-compiler

I am trying to implement this code but I am getting the following compiler error: `randn wasn't declared in the scope`.

```
void levyflt()
{
  int j;
  double beta=1.5,sigma,rand_num;

  sigma=pow((tgamma(1+beta)*sin(M_PI*beta/2)/(tgamma((1+beta)/2)*beta*pow(2,((beta-1)/2)))),(1/beta));

  for(j=0;j<d;j++)
  {

    rand_num=randn(-1,1);
    u[j]=rand_num*sigma;
    rand_num=randn(-1,1);

    v[j]=rand_num;
    step[j]=u[j]/pow(fabs(v[j]),(1/beta));
    L[j]=0.01*step[j];
  }


  cout<<L[j];
}
```

Comment: Why the MATLAB tag? Are you trying to generate a MEX file?

Comment: `randn` isn't a thing, unless you make it so.

Comment: noo...but randn is a matlab fxn

Comment: @juanchopanza....so i have to use user defined function??

Comment: How are you trying to integrate  a MATLAB function into C++?

Comment: @user3551520 If you want it to be called `randn`, yes. What is your real problem here?

Comment: Are you trying to make a MEX file?  `randn` doesn't exist in MATLAB's MEX libraries.  You have to create the function yourself, or use `mexCallMATLAB` to call the function from within MATLAB.

Comment: m getting error that 'randn wasn't declared in the scope??

Comment: @suleman....i have read somewhere that we can use randn in c++ code also....please guide me if m wrong

Comment: @user3551520 - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/

Comment: @rayryeng....ohkz thanku so much

Comment: You should take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random

Comment: if anyone knows about levy flight can we use uniformly distributed random nos instead of gaussian??

Answer (score 1):

You need Matlab Compiler SDK for this. Using the Matlab Compiler SDK, you will be able to export the specific Matlab functionality you need, in your case perhaps `randn` function. The Compiler SDK generates .dll, .lib, and .h files for the Matlab function you want to export. You can then call the function in the shared library from C++ using the `mwArray` library built specifically for marshalling data between Matlab generated dll and your C++ code. All of this is documented [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/02/03/creating-c-shared-libraries-and-dlls/).

P.S. I heard that they recently separated Matlab Compiler from the Matlab Compiler SDK, so be careful about what you purchase.

This is strictly an answer to your question as stated, random number generation facilities in C++ 11 will probably serve you best as @drescherjm correctly points out in the comments.

Comment: @user3551520 I say you are better off taking a look at the c++11 random support than using MATLAB this way. You have already been given links for that in the comments of your question.

Comment: Yes, Matlab Compiler SDK will create a shared library for you to use on whatever platform you are on using Qt. You need to include header files from Matlab installation `Include` folder. Also, you need to include the header that was generated at the time of creating shared library. Then you need to do the same for .libs. Do you have Mathworks Tech support? They will walk you through the whole process. But yeah, why aren't you using C++11 facilities for random number generation?

Comment: @user3551520 If you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as the answer to your question.